# Cradview left space between items

Tags: android, xml, cardview

my problem is with Cardview in Android Studio.I am parsing data from XML feed and using cardview to display it.Everything seems okay, but cardview left free space after every row. My code from layout is below.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Small Text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_img"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_text"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumb_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#006699"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumb_img"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to change your `cardview` height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` and also you need to change your `relativelayout` height as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `CardView` and `RelativeLayout` height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

Use changes layout XML this will fix your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Small Text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumb_img"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_text"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumb_img"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#006699"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumb_img"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Right now, you're telling android to make the cardview the height of the wrapping layout, and I think what you want is for it to just take up as much height as it needs to display you information.